# Displaying dynamic data in an ItemsControl as a responsive grid

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I'm writing an app that'll allow me to monitor the operational status of websites that I host for my business and clients to maintain a decent uptime on the sites.

I've got most of the app done, but I've hit a bit of a layout snag in rendering the status for each site on the UI which I'm doing with an ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Sites, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <materialDesign:Card Margin="5" Width="220" Padding="5">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        FontSize="20" 
                        Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignHeadlineTextBlock}"
                        Text="{Binding Name}" 
                        TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" Kind="Web"
                        Visibility="{Binding OkayIconVisibility}"
                        Height="50" Width="50" />
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" Kind="Alert"
                        Visibility="{Binding AlertIconVisibility}"
                        Height="50" Width="50" />
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Text="{Binding Status}" 
                        TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </materialDesign:Card>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This works except that it only stacks them on top of each other.

What I'd prefer is a horizontal stack that wraps with overflow - so to speak.

The Window is `MinWidth="450"` so there could be at least 2 sites listed on a row and sites 3 and 4 go beneath them.

I've seen a few posts on creating a custom ItemsControl or setting up a grid as a template for the ItemsControl but those mostly work with a fixed number of items which makes it easier.

I'm very much at a loss as to how I should proceed here. If I could set up a container for the items within the ItemsControl that would suit me perfectly because I can at least work with that. As it is, I don't see how to go about this.

Comment: you can change ItemsControl.ItemsPanelTemplate to WrapPanel. default is a stack panel which stacks items on top of each other

Comment: @ASh I don't have an `ItemsControl.ItemsPanelTemplate` so I don't know where the WrapPanel is supposed to go

Answer (score 0):

You can use WrapPanel as `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Sites, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel></WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    ...
</ItemsControl>
```

This will stack your `Site` items horizontally and wraps items when it overflows as you prefer it.